# Can I directly load text with numbers in CCC,CC format ? (K4)

Tags: kdb

I have input with floats stored like 1000,50, ie. the decimal points are replaced by commas.
Is there an option in K to load these numbers directly into floats ?
When using

`data:("SFF" ;";",";") 0:. filename`
I get 0ns, of course, because the numbers are not recognized as floats.
I load them as strings now, and convert them using ssr like
`c:.:' .q.ssr'[data;",";"."]`
but that is extremely slow.

Is there an option somewhere to have K load these numbers in CCC,CC format as floats directly ? Normal format and ccc,cc format are not mixed, any file has just one of them.
If there is not, I imagine that it must by quite easy to replace a "." somewhere in the Q-binary where the load-function sits, with a ",", to get a version which loads these numbers. Has anybody tried that ? Or any other tip to load big files with these numbers in reasonable time ?

Cheers,
Co

Comment: I don't think there's any way to direct-parse it cleanly. You could pre-process the file before ever loading it into kdb. I'm sure some linux command/tool could replace the commas with dots much quicker than loading into kdb and doing it in there.

Answer (score 2):

If `ssr'` is slow for your task you may find this tiny function useful:

```
c2p:{c:-1_sums count each x;p:ss[r:raze x;","];r[p]:".";(0,c) _ r}
```

**Update:** an alternative version:

```
c2p:{p:ss[r:raze x;","];r[p]:".";(0,-1_sums count'[x])_r}
```

It concatenates all strings into a single long string, finds positions of commas, replaces commas with periods then splits that long string:

```
q)N:1000000
q)s:string[N?100000],'",",'string N?1000

q)\t r1:ssr'[s;",";"."]
4284
q)\t r2:c2p s
242
q)r1~r2
1b
```

Comment: That is much better, indeed. On the system here, 10 times faster, but that is still good

Comment: Unless all your floats conform to a certain format (e.g. always have 2 digits after decimal point) you can hardly do better in q/k IMHO

Answer (score 0):

I was thinking something like find (?) combined with indexing/applying

```
    q)N:1000000
    q)s:string[N?100000],'",",'string N?1000
    q)\ts {s[x;y]:"."}./:flip(til count s;s?\:",")
    967 52972144
    q)s
    "93912.794"
    "57144.788"
    "77809.659"
    "7839.47"
    "6363.523"
    "44761.244"
    "65699.712"
```

It's not perfect but that's the general idea. I'm sure there is an easier way...